# Android setting progress bar in the center of the screen

Tags: android

```
    LinearLayout spinnerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    addContentView(spinnerLayout,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(this);
    spinnerLayout.addView(spinner);
```

Of course, the spinner is in the top left corner. I've searched and found the xml method, but I want a java solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    LinearLayout spinnerLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    spinnerLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    addContentView(spinnerLayout,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(this);
    spinnerLayout.addView(spinner);
```

That should work